# Always launching google chrome in incognito mode

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, selenium

I am using ubuntu 20.04. I want to launch google chrome always in incognito mode by default. Is this possible in ubuntu. I read its not a common practice to do this. And will it have any effect if we use selenium chrome driver for scraping purpose if opened in incognito mode.

Note : Since I am new user please upvote the question to get me more features opened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can amend `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` so it runs

```
google-chrome --incognito
```

But it will be replaced on Chrome updates.

So make a copy of this `.desktop` file and name it differently.